# Hide border of label

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to hide border of label that appears when pressed on. That is, the border around the i button. I have tried setting outline and border to 0 and even to none but nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#popoverData').popover();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
<label for="download" style="float: left; margin-top: 6px">Content</label>
        <a id="popoverData" class="btn" href="#" data-content="My Content" 
        rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover" style="float: left; margin-left: -10px; margin-top: 0px; border: none;">&#x1F6C8;</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Setting `outline: none;` for the element should hide that "border". You say this fails, maybe the element showing the outline is not what you think it is (most likely it's the `a` element).

Comment: Never remove the focus outline without replacing it with another clear focus indicator. Otherwise you are excluding everyone using a keyboard or similar inputs, which is way more people than one might think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you refer to the `box-shadow` of the `a.btn`, you can remove it by adding the following CSS rule :

```css
.btn:active {
  box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#popoverData').popover();
});
```

```css
.btn:active {
  box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
<label for="download" style="float: left; margin-top: 6px">Content</label>
        <a id="popoverData" class="btn" href="#" data-content="My Content" 
        rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover" style="float: left; margin-left: -10px; margin-top: 0px; border: none;">&#x1F6C8;</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi yes thank you that was it :) was it the shadow? Can I just set the shadow as none in the style tag?

Comment: @Vika Yes you could replace `border: none` with `box-shadow: none` in your example.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean: If you click and hold on the button, it's the shadow which appears (see previous answer), but if you just click the button and release the mouse, it will be focused. So in this case you can add a CSS rule for the `focus` state, like this:

```
a#popoverData:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

But note that this will be against accessibility rules, since people navigating only by keyboard actions will not see anymore which element is selected/focused.

Full example (i.e. above rule simply added to the code in the question):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#popoverData').popover();
});
```

```css
a#popoverData:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <div>
    <label for="download" style="float: left; margin-top: 6px">Content</label>
    <a id="popoverData" class="btn" href="#" data-content="My Content" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover" style="float: left; margin-left: -10px; margin-top: 0px; border: none;">&#x1F6C8;</a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```